# Looking for ideas to design and implement a tasks management system

Tags: .net, sharepoint-workflow

Gurus:

I need to design a tasks management system for a client to supplement an enterprise solution that uses ASP.net MVC, SQL Server 2008, and Workflow Foundation. What would be the best technology to accomplish the following:
1. Be able to create and edit tasks (and assign them to individuals).
2. Have task dependencies - hierarchical tasks with parent-child relationship.
3. Notification mechanism: Notified parties involved about the status of the task when it changes.
4. Workflow management: completion of a certain task should automatically spawn generation and assignment of new tasks.

I have started looking at MS SharePoint today, but would like to know from you if there is something out there that I could readily use.

Thanks,
Ritesh

Answer (score 0):

i love love love sysaid from http://www.ilient.com/

the support is outstanding and the product is simple and very easy to configure in anyway you want. it will more than satisfy your requirements

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am looking for something that exposes its functionality through an API and I could use the ASP.net MVC web application as the front end. Do you think SysAid would do this?

Comment: For future readers, note not everyone loves SysAid. I find it the most astonishingly terrible piece of crap I've ever used, and I use a lot of Oracle software.
As for their support, we sent a list of major bugs categorized by six levels of severity (there were that many). Of those, zero have been fixed in the two years we've used the software.
Ask me about its design sometimes. Hint: The developers don't understand what AJAX is for: They resend the entire (HUGE) document, including HTML, with each refresh. Just incredible.